# How to get rid of the ugly white line around dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

Im trying to get rid of the ugly white outline around the UI Dialog..

https://receptenplaats.nl/hmpf.png <- picture of the dialog

I searched and searched google and stackoverflow..
and i come across this solution:

```
      .ui-widget-content {
        border: none !important;
    outline-width: 0px !important;
      }
```

But this isn't working..

Anybody has a other solution that does the trick?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal representation of your problem in snippet it would be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Im trying to remove the outline/border (white line) around the dialog box.. or a way to give it a other color then white.. because as u can see on the picture the white line is ugly and doesn't fit in the design.. i did try the code that i have included in the post and that isn't working.

Comment: yeah, but without seeing we cannot tell that you are applying the code to the correct div that causing the line or maybe you are trying where there is nothing, so why dont you give a border to that class as `border: 5px solid red` and see if that white line changes to red if not give `background: red` if that changes. or you can share the link or code maybe

Comment: `.ui-dialog{ padding : 0 !important;}` .. the point is the space with the white line its from padding not from border or outline .. you may also need to use `ui-resizable-handle{display : none !important;}`

Comment: .ui-dialog{ padding : 0 !important;} / That did the trick... Now its gone :)!! Thnx alot Mohamed Yousef you are a genius !!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the standard [jQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), there is a class that overrides the default `ui-widget-content` class. Try the following:

```
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thnx alot for your time to anwsher / Dankjewel! But the code i needed was: .ui-dialog{ padding : 0 !important;} / like Mohamed-Yousef pointed out